# What do dyes do?

Tags: terraria-mobile

The dye trader sells dyes and I don't know what they do. Do they dye clothes to make them look better? Or do they have effects on you if you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All they do are change the colors of your armor and clothes. This can be helpful if you're in PVP and going for a team look, if you want a certain color scheme, or don't want to run around in, say, pink armor, for example.